# Hours of attempting to install django and stuck on an urls.py error

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

I have spend the past 6 hours getting an ubuntu 10.04 server setup with django and mysql. I am using django 1.2.1, and maybe that's my problem. I have everything as I'd think it should be and am receiving this error when I hit http://localhost/admin

```
Request URL:   http://192.168.1.153/mydangoproject/admin
Django Version:     1.2.1
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named mydangoproject.urls

Exception Location:      /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Hard to help you without any details of your Apache configuration or your urls.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of `ROOT_URLCONF` in your `settings.py` and try settings it to just `'urls'`. And make sure you have a valid `urls.py` in your Django project root directory.

Also, is the "dangoproject" (without a J) misspelling intentional?